# Update Document in couchdb with C#

Tags: c#, couchdb

I would like to update a document in my couchDB. I am using C# with the Couch.driver 3.4.0.
I always get the error message:
System.InvalidOperationException: "Cannot add or update a document without an ID."

```
public class Runner
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {

        await using Worker context = new Worker();
        var client = context.Client.GetDatabase<Person>("data-eins");
        Person p1 = new Person();
        p1.Name = "Olga";
        p1.Job = "Arzt";
        Person p2 = new Person();
        p2.Name = "Ilse";
        p2.Job = "Koch";
        if (context.MyPerson != null)
        {
           // var ergo = await client.AddAsync(p1);
           // Console.WriteLine(ergo.toString());
            // var ergo2 = await client.AddOrUpdateAsync(p2);
            //     Console.WriteLine(ergo2.toString());
            var result = await client.QueryAsync("{\"selector\": { \"_id\": {\"$gt\": null} }}");
            Person myP = new Person();
            foreach (Person p in result)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(p.toString());
                if (p.Name == "Harry") {
                    p.Job = "Rentner";
                    Console.WriteLine("##########");
                    Console.WriteLine(p.toString());
                    Console.WriteLine("##########");
                    
                    await client.AddOrUpdateAsync(p, new AddOrUpdateOptions { Rev=p._rev  });
                    
                }
            }
            //await client.RemoveAsync(myP);// .AddOrUpdateAsync(myP);
            
            Console.WriteLine(result.Count);
        }
        else {
            Console.WriteLine("Context ist null");
        }  
    }
}
```

"Cannot add or update a document without an ID."